# Binding a Swift library to use in Xamarin, without Mac OS, is it possible?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, binding, xamarin.ios

I have not used Xamarin before, I'm coming from a native development background.

I have a question about the feasibility of binding a native iOS library written in Swift, in order to use it in an Xamarin project. Is this possible and more importantly is it possible to do without any access to a Mac OS computer?

As a side question, is Objective-C library binding doable without Mac OS?

Comment: As far as I know, to build an iOS target you will need a Mac.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm aware that to build the app I would need a Mac (this can be done using a build host on a remote server, no?). I was more curious about the binding of a library, since that would be the more complex part (especially if I only have access to a Mac OS build host).

Answer (score 1):

To do the entire process: No.

You can create a Xamarin Binding project from within Visual Studio, but there are a lot of dependencies you will need that you can only get by having access to a macOS.

1 - If you don't have the compiled and fat library you will need a macOS to build using Xcode and use Lipo to create the fat library.

2 - Supposing you already have it, you will need to create the ApiDefinition.cs, to do so you might use [Objective Sharpie](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/getting-started/) (macOS only). You can get around it by creating it manually, but unless you are binding a very tiny library - just for the sake of proving the point - you will not want to do so.

Those two apply to any Xamarin.iOS Binding, as it is the same process for [Objective-C Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/)

3 - For Swift Bindings you will also need to include all Swift dependencies inside SwiftSupport folder inside your IPA file. This step is required before publishing the App, not creating the binding - I have only tried to do so using a shell script. But for this case you need a macOS to publish the app to App Store as well.

So just to prove the point: Maybe.

Comment: That's an insightful contribution ! it should have more upvotes